# Angular 16 app with Firebase 9 - Service storage is not available error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I currently have an Angular v16 app with @angular/fire: ^7.6.1 and firebase: ^9.0.0. I have added Firebase and Angular Fire to the project and have initialised it all.

I have a contact form, which takes full name, email, phone, subject, message and an attachment. I want to send the user data to Firestore, whereby I can then forward on to an email address via my index.ts code (not shown). I assume I will have to save the attachment as a downloadURL?

When I press submit I am faced with the following error -
Error: Service storage is not available
at Provider.getImmediate
at getStorage
at ContactUsComponent.onSubmit

I ran npm ls @firebase/app and am faced with the following tree, which might be the issue?

```
─┬ @angular/fire@7.6.1
│ └─┬ firebase@9.23.0
│   ├─┬ @firebase/analytics@0.10.0
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/app-check@0.8.0
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/app-compat@0.2.13
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.13 deduped
│   ├── @firebase/app@0.9.13
│   ├─┬ @firebase/auth@0.23.2
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.13 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/firestore@3.13.0
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.13 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/functions@0.10.0
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/installations@0.6.4
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/messaging@0.12.4
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/performance@0.6.4
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   ├─┬ @firebase/remote-config@0.4.4
│   │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
│   └─┬ @firebase/storage@0.11.2
│     └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
└─┬ firebase@9.0.0
  ├─┬ @firebase/analytics@0.7.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/app-check@0.4.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/app-compat@0.1.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├── @firebase/app@0.7.0
  ├─┬ @firebase/auth-compat@0.1.0
  │ └─┬ @firebase/app-compat@0.2.14
  │   └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/auth@0.17.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14
  ├─┬ @firebase/firestore@3.0.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.9.14 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/functions@0.7.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/installations@0.5.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/messaging@0.9.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/performance@0.5.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @firebase/remote-config@0.2.0
  │ └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
  └─┬ @firebase/storage@0.8.0
    └── @firebase/app@0.7.0 deduped
```

app.module.ts

```
// other standard imports NgModule, etc 
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator  } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getAuth, provideAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getFunctions, provideFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099', { disableWarnings: true });
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

contact-us.component

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (file.size > 5242880) {
        alert('File is too large!');
        this.contactForm.get('attachment').setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
      } else {
        this.fileName = file.name;
        this.contactForm.get('attachment').setValue(file);  // store the file in the form control
      }
    }
    // NOT SURE IF NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS? 
    // const filePath = `emails/${this.emailId}/${this.file.name}`;
    // const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, this.file, {
    //   cacheControl: "max-age=31536000,public"
    // })
  }
```

```
onSubmit() {
    const value = this.contactForm.value;
    const file = value.attachment;
    const newEmail: Partial<Contact> = {
      fullName: value.fullName,
      email: value.email,
      phone: value.phone,
      subject: value.subject,
      message: value.message,
      attachmentUrl: '',
    }
    if (this.contactForm.valid) {
      console.log("is form valid: ", this.contactForm.valid); 

      this.loading = true;
      // REACHES HERE AND THEN FALLS OVER
      // Upload the file to Firebase Storage
      const firebaseApp = getApp();
      const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
      const fileRef = ref(storage, file.name);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, file);

      uploadTask.then((snapshot: { ref: any; }) => {
        return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref); 
      }).then((downloadURL) => {
        newEmail.attachmentUrl = downloadURL as string; 

          this.contactService.sendContact(newEmail, this.emailId).pipe(
            tap(email => {
              this.loading = false;
              this.contactForm.reset();
              this.messageSuccessMessage = true;
              setTimeout(() => this.messageSuccessMessage = false, 3000);
            }),
            catchError(error => {
              this.loading = false;
              this.messageFailureMessage = true;
              setTimeout(() => this.messageFailureMessage = false, 3000);
              return throwError(error);
            })
          ).subscribe()
        }).catch((error: any) => {
          console.error('Upload failed:', error);
      });
    }
    else {
      this.contactForm.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was down to two versions of Firebase being installed. I removed Firebase, Firebase Tools and Angular Fire, removed the node modules, npm i and then reinstalled everything to the appropriate versions.